# Connect back to main container from GitlabCI service

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab CI with docker executor and [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/).

During test I'm starting a server in the main script, and I need the service to make a request back to the main script.

Is there address/alias I can use to connect back to the main build script? Something like [`host.docker.internal`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host).

Pseudo-example:

```yaml
test:
  services:
    name: ping-pong-service
    variables:
      CALLBACK_ADDRESS: 'http://host.docker.internal:8090/pong'
  script:
  - "Start a server at 0.0.0.0:8090"
  - curl http://ping-pong-service:80/ping
```

Supose that `ping-pong-service` is a service that when receiving any http request on :80, performs new request to `CALLBACK_ADDRESS`. What should I enter into `CALLBACK_ADDRESS` to connect back to main container?

I tried looking into what containers get started on the runner, but the main container doesn't seem to have predictable name or alias in the docker network.

---

Env:

- Docker: 20.10.12
- Gitlab Runner: 14.8.0, self-hosted, FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD=1
- Gitlab: 14.9.2-ee, self-hosted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` feature flag for [networks per job](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#create-a-network-for-each-job), containers started using `services:` can reach the main job container using the network alias `build`

Assuming your service is configured as you describe, you would use:

```yaml
variables:
  CALLBACK_ADDRESS: 'http://build:8090/pong'
```

Note: this does not apply to containers started using `docker run` in the job container for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, works! Is this documented anywhere to have a canonical source?

Comment: @michalhosna yes, it is documented in the link in the answer :)

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't se it. Thanks!